# How do I cache Handler files and images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I would like to set an expiry and still, to check if the file or image has been modified. Please note that the images are retrieved from a SQL Server database.

I also prefer if caching would be done on IIS and not on c# code in Handler file.

I haven't come up with anything yet.

Thank you.

Comment: why this is on hold? user asked for an IIS solution to caching. How is that too broad?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an http handler called Handler.ashx in your root folder, the following changes to web.config will instruct IIS to cache the output for 1 day:

```
<location path="Handler.ashx">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="max-age" value="86400"></add>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

you could also set expires header. http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/